# How to get an Environment Module modulefile to print a message upon loading the module?

Tags: linux, environment-modules

I've just learned the basics on how to make [modulefiles](http://modules.sourceforge.net/man/modulefile.html) for loading software on my cluster. Other environment modules (created by admins) print a message upon loading:

`$ module load Name
Welcome to Name/version.1.2.3`

How do I add this to the modulefile? I like the quick confirmation that I've indeed loaded the module I intended. I've tried a few things from the [man page](http://modules.sourceforge.net/man/modulefile.html) (ex `module-info name`) but no luck (or I'm doing it wrong).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you "only" want the message to print when running `module load` (but not when running `module unload` or other commands), then you can use a statement like this:

```
if [ module-info mode load ] {
    puts stderr "your text here"
}
```

Reference: https://sourceforge.net/p/modules/mailman/message/34597600/

Comment: I seemed to have figured this out a few years ago and this code is what I have been using. Thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 2):

You can add `puts stderr` statements to modulefile, for printing messages to terminal.

```
puts stderr "** INFO: 'Welcome, Module loaded'"
```